# How to calculate the neighbouring grids on geohash. Algorithms required

Tags: node.js, algorithm, geohashing

Hi I am working with a database with an implementation of geohash

[image]

[image]

So as shown above, as the zoom level goes down (6 zoom levels), more of `abcd` gets inserted into each grid. I have represented them as a rigid grid; however, the central point is different for all the grids. So for example, distance from `a` to `b` will not be the same as distance from `a` to `c`.

If it was a rigid grid, I can just get the closest four neighbouring grids; however, I cannot do that as the distances vary and the closest neighbours are not necessarily orthogonal. Only information that I have from the database is the centra point of each grid and the geohash key e.g. `aa`, `ab`, etc..

How will I find girds that are just north, west, east and south of each grid for every zoom level? (have 6 zoom levels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see a cell that ends in, for example, `d`, has a cell with the same prefix but ending in `b` north of it. This allows you to set up a mapping table.

In the cases where, like `cb` going north, you end up at `ad`, the trick is to recognize that going north from `*b` you need to look at the previous character (in this case, the `c`), go north from that character (`a`) and add the south-most edge of that column (`d`).

In short, it's a matter of implementing some mapping tables and some logic to deal with the edges.